# Angular event listener not appearing in tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, karma-runner, mocha.js

Lets say I have a directive:

```
angular.module('foo').directive('myDir', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function (scope) {
      var watcher = scope.$watch('foo, function () {});
      scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        watcher();
      });
    }
  }
})
```

And then the following test:

```
describe('myDir', function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    module('foo');
    inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
      var scope = $rootScope.$new();
      $compile('<my-dir></my-dir>')(scope);
      scope.$digest();
    });
  });

  it('listens for destroy', function () {
    expect(scope.$$listeners.$destroy).to.not.equal(undefined);
  });
});
```

Which fails with:
`Error: expected undefined to not equal undefined`

Oddly if I `console.log(scope.$$listeners.$destroy)` directly before my `expect`, the log shows an array of functions, not undefined, but the test still fails.

What is causing the listeners to be invisible to the assertion? Is there a good workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Changing from `.to.not.equal`

to

`not.to.be`

fixed the problem